# Pygame- Running two things at the same time

Tags: python, timer, pygame

I'm creating a typing game that basically shows a word, then checks to see if you typed the word, then moves to a next one. I want this all to be done under a timer. The thing is, well the timer and the game cant run at the same time, any idea on how to do this, here is the code (more will be provided if needed):

```
def countdown():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    done = False

    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)

    frame_count = 0
    frame_rate = 60
    start_time = 15

    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
                pygame.quit()
                quit()# Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

        button("",600,0,200,50,white,white)


        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT

        # --- Timer going up ---
        # Calculate total seconds
        total_seconds = frame_count // frame_rate

        # Divide by 60 to get total minutes
        minutes = total_seconds // 60

        # Use modulus (remainder) to get seconds
        seconds = total_seconds % 60

        # --- Timer going down ---
        # --- Timer going up ---
        # Calculate total seconds
        total_seconds = start_time - (frame_count // frame_rate)
        if total_seconds < 0:
            total_seconds = 0

        # Divide by 60 to get total minutes
        minutes = total_seconds // 60

        # Use modulus (remainder) to get seconds
        seconds = total_seconds % 60

        # Use python string formatting to format in leading zeros
        output_string = "Time left: {0:02}:{1:02}".format(minutes, seconds)

        # Blit to the screen
        text = font.render(output_string, True, black)

        gameDisplay.blit(text, [600, 0])
        pygame.display.update()

        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT
        frame_count += 1
        # Limit to 20 frames per second
        clock.tick(frame_rate)

        # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
        pygame.display.update()
def gameLoop(level):
    pygame.display.update()
    if level == '1':
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        keyboard()
        for turn in range(3):
            randWord()
            count = 0
            while count < len(chars):
                if chars[count] == 'a':
                    key("A",132.5,430,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_a
                elif chars[count] == 'b':
                    key("B",342.5,470,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_b
                elif chars[count] == 'c':
                    key("C",252.5,470,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_c
                elif chars[count] == 'd':
                    key("D",222.5,430,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_d
                elif chars[count] == 'e':
                    key("E",207.5,390,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_e
                elif chars[count] == 'f':
                    key("F",267.5,430,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_f
                elif chars[count] == 'g':
                    key("G",312.5,430,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_g
                elif chars[count] == 'h':
                    key("H",357.5,430,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_h
                elif chars[count] == 'i':
                    key("I",432.5,390,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_i
                elif chars[count] == 'j':
                    key("J",402.5,430,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_j
                elif chars[count] == 'k':
                    key("K",447.5,430,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_k
                elif chars[count] == 'l':
                    key("L",492.5,430,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_l
                elif chars[count] == 'm':
                    key("M",432.5,470,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_m
                elif chars[count] == 'n':
                    key("N",387.5,470,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_n
                elif chars[count] == 'o':
                    key("O",477.5,390,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_o
                elif chars[count] == 'p':
                    key("P",522.5,390,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_p
                elif chars[count] == 'q':
                    key("Q",117.5,390,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_q
                elif chars[count] == 'r':
                    key("R",252.5,390,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_r
                elif chars[count] == 's':
                    key("S",177.5,430,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_s
                elif chars[count] == 't':
                    key("T",297.5,390,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_t
                elif chars[count] == 'u':
                    key("U",387.5,390,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_u
                elif chars[count] == 'v':
                    key("V",297.5,470,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_v
                elif chars[count] == 'w':
                    key("W",162.5,390,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_w
                elif chars[count] == 'x':
                    key("X",207.5,470,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_x
                elif chars[count] == 'y':
                    key("Y",342.5,390,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_y
                elif chars[count] == 'z':
                    key("Z",162.5,470,45,40,white)
                    letter = pygame.K_z
                pygame.display.update()
                true = True
                while true:
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                            if event.key == letter:
                                keyboard()
                                count += 1
                                pygame.display.update()
                                true = False
                countdown()
        finishLevel()
```

Comment: Your countdown is outside of a while true, do you expect to break out of that at some point?

Comment: I'm not familiar with *pygame*, but if you want things to be done in "parallel" in Python, you should explore `multiprocessing` module. (You can also use `threading.Thread` but due to *GIL* in cPython's threads, nothing can be done in parallel.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pygame.time.set_timer(eventid, milliseconds)`. `eventid` is 24 in the current version of pygame. For more timers at once, use `eventid` 25,26, and so on. When a timer goes off, it will generate a `pygame.USEREVENT` event in the event queue that you can get with `pygame.event.get()`, which I am assuming you know how to use.

Comment: can you explain a little more on event ids, please?

Comment: eventids are what pygame uses to keep track of events. using values less than 24 will replace a different event that pygame has built in.

Comment: so how would i use pygame.event.get() in this situation? would I check for an event called pygame.USEREVENT or something else

Comment: Yes, just add                                                                                                  if event==pygame.USEREVENT: after if event==pygame.QUIT:

Comment: will this timer keep repeating, or just run once?

Comment: it will keep repeating. if you want it to stop use pygame.time.set_timer(eventid of timer to be deleted, 0)

Comment: do you have any idea on how to put the remaining time on-screen

Comment: i do not know how to do that. the only thing i could think would be to use a one second (1000 milliseconds) timer and every time it goes off you could subtract one from a timeLeft variable and put that on the screen.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it helped you?

Comment: when I check for the event, nothing is triggered

Comment: make sure you set the timer outside of the main loop.

Comment: it works! Thank you. This did help, a lot. I might have some further questions though, so stay tuned

Comment: For more questions, actually post a new question instead of using comments. By the way, upvoting and accepting are different things.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: its okay, i am pretty new too.

Answer (score 1):

You can update as many things and draw as many things at the same time, but you need them in the same loop. I would propose for you to restructure the program a bit like so.

```
class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        timer = Timer()
        game = Game()
    def run():
        while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
                    pygame.quit()
                timer.handle_event(event)
                game.handle_event(event)
            timer.update()
            game.update()
            timer.draw(screen)
            game.draw(screen)

class Game:
    #will include all game logic

class Timer:
    #will include all timer logic
```

You could also extract the timer and pass the updated ms into the update method so that later on the Game object will be able to calculate some time based movement as well.